# mySql problem in MySqlDataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, database, datareader

MySqlDataReader  rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

i have a some information in my mysqldatareader.
how can i show it on our web-pages

I don't know how i can use it .it means mysqldatareader.

also welcome for simple source code.

Comment: Was this really worth a downvote with not so much as a comment? It's a valid question, poorly worded though it may be...

Comment: Sorry for all. I have a problem firstly i not know english well.
so don't worry i also thing for improvement it

Comment: Don't worry about it... it's perfectly understandable. Some people are just a bit obtuse with their clicky fingers... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a full explanation of the MySqlDataReader with example code, check out the MySQL site: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqldatareader.html

Comment: Very very thanks for support me and pardon for poorly worded question

Comment: Not a problem at all. I get enough support from this site I owe it to help somebody... I think we all do.